# open Ionic app Android from browser

Tags: android, ionic-framework

In my AndroidManifest.xml I stated the following as an example:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:host="mywebsite.com" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:path="/.*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And in the browser :

```
<a href="intent://mywebsite.com/#Intent;package=my.package.app;scheme=http;end;"/>Click
```

And I only get the application in Google Play, no spear as I hope, that I'll be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic syntax for an intent-based URI is as follows:

intent: HOST/URI-path // Optional host #Intent; package=[string]; action=[string]; category=[string]; component=[string]; scheme=[string]; end;

In your URI, you forgot to define the action.

Comment: Ammmm .. I will look how to define action

Comment: As it would be with the action in the URI?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: [Launch custom android application from android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

You used http as the scheme, so the link on your website should also start with http://

Comment: Had tried that but I get the same result, the play opens store